# Need notification when timer is done, before next interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i want notification when the timer is done, not only 'OFFSET', someone can help me? Thanks.

edit: So that script is basically a timer that suppose to give me a notification on my discord channel every hour and 1 minute. Right now I only get a notification that target is X minutes away. I want another notification when the actual timer is done (before next interval).

edit2: I don't want to create another topic, so anybody can help me to add seconds to that? Now is the only timer for hours with minutes and I want to add seconds to that.
So instead: 20:50
i want: 20:50:20

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var bot = new Discord.Client();

var NOTIFY_CHANNEL;
bot.on('ready', () => {
    NOTIFY_CHANNEL = bot.channels.cache.get('xxx'); // Channel to send notification
});

const START_DATE = '2020-08-15'; // Date used as the starting point for multi-hour intervals, must be YYYY-MM-DD format
const START_HOUR = 19; // Hour of the day when the timer begins (0 is 12am, 23 is 11pm), used with START_DATE and INTERVAL_HOURS param
const INTERVAL_HOURS = 1; // Trigger at an interval of every X hours
const TARGET_MINUTE = 1; // Minute of the hour when the chest will refresh, 30 means 1:30, 2:30, etc.
const OFFSET = 5; // Notification will warn that the target is X minutes away


const NOTIFY_MINUTE = (TARGET_MINUTE < OFFSET ? 60 : 0) + TARGET_MINUTE - OFFSET;
console.log('Notification sent');
const START_TIME = new Date(new Date(START_DATE).getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 + START_HOUR * 3600000).getTime();

setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    if (Math.floor((d.getTime() - START_TIME) / 3600000) % INTERVAL_HOURS > 0) return; // Return if hour is not the correct interval
    if (d.getMinutes() !== NOTIFY_MINUTE) return; // Return if current minute is not the notify minute
    NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send('in: ' + OFFSET + 'minutes');
}, 60 * 1000); // Check every minute


bot.login('xxx');
```

Comment: Please explain your issue in more detail. Strange how your code comments are more detailed than trying to explain to us exactly what your specific problem is. Writing a properly detailed question takes a bit more effort than just a partial ambiguous sentence and a code dump

Comment: Im getting notification in chat that, timer is about to end in 'offset'. But i cant write notification when timer is done.

Comment: Edit the question with your clarifications and explain in more detail what is currently happening and how it needs to behave differently as well as any troubleshooting you have done

Comment: Ok so that's a bit better nd getting closer to explaining the issue. Not really clear what constitutes *"timer is done"* though

Comment: i just want a notification every 1 hour and 1 minute, not only how much minutes away

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you want to remove

> if (d.getMinutes() !== NOTIFY_MINUTE)

change the timer you already have

> NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send('in: ' + OFFSET + 'minutes');

to

> if (d.getMinutes() == NOTIFY_MINUTE) NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send('in: ' + OFFSET + 'minutes');

and add

> if (d.getMinutes() == TARGET_MINUTE) NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send('in: ' + OFFSET + 'minutes');

to notify at target minute,

which leave us with

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    if (Math.floor((d.getTime() - START_TIME) / 3600000) % INTERVAL_HOURS > 0) return; // Return if hour is not the correct interval
    // if (d.getMinutes() !== NOTIFY_MINUTE) return; // Return if current minute is not the notify minute
    if (d.getMinutes() == NOTIFY_MINUTE) NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send('in: ' + OFFSET + 'minutes');
    if (d.getMinutes() == TARGET_MINUTE) NOTIFY_CHANNEL.send("It's now");
}, 60 * 1000); // Check every minute
```